# iOS Text view in Scroll View does not show all text when scrolled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview, constraints

I am working with Xcode 5 for iOS 7 with storyboards. I have a Table View Controller that links (with Push segue) to a "detail page" View Controller with about 50+ lines of text. I want to scroll through the text (in both Portrait and Landscape) with the text constraints set to leading and trailing space to superview so that it fills the screen on both orientations. The text spans the width of the screen but it does not scroll a button I placed to be after the text. I want to scroll to the bottom of the text to view the button, but the image a) stays in the same position in portrait and b) doesn't appear in landscape.

I have the following hierarchy:
+ View Controller
  + View
    + Scroll View
      - Text View
      - Image
      + Constraints
    + Constraints

Note: The constraints were done by reset to suggested constraints in View Controller.
I am working with Attributed, Word Wrap.

All input helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to accomplish this would be adding contentInset at bottom of UITextView, and place your button there. In storyboard put button inside UITextView and add constant constraint between bottom of button and bottom of UITextView.